# Jquery: new FadeToggle, can i run code on the 2nd action of the toggle?

Tags: jquery, toggle

so when i click `#mybutton` it will fade in `.mybox`. is it possible to take my code below, and add something like `.animate({'width':'toggle'})` or add a `.delay(2000)` before the first time it's toggled, then not activate the delay when the toggle is activated the second time? 
how would i do that? easiest/simplest way?

here's my code to work with:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
  $('.mybox').fadeToggle(500)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind a one-time event handler, then binding the "real" permanent event handler will would work here:

```
var box = $('#box');

$('a').one('click', function(){
    box.delay(2000).fadeToggle();
    $(this).click(function(){
        box.fadeToggle();
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

See this simple demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/2m3bb/

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it, using [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```
var firstClick = true; 

$('#mybutton').click(function(){
  if (firstClick) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          $('.mybox').fadeToggle(500);
          firstClick = false; // #mybutton has been clicked once, we no longer want to wait before toggling on subsequent clicks of #mybutton 
      });
  } else {
      $('.mybox').fadeToggle(500);
  }      
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just `toggle()` instead of `fadeToggle()` to get a bit more control.

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
var firstTime = true;
$('.mybox').toggle(
    function () {
        $(this).fadeIn(500);
    },
    function () {
        if (firstTime)
        { $(this).delay(2000); }
        $(this).animate({'width':'toggle'}).fadeOut(500);
    }
);
})
```